# How to truncate extraneous output using shell script?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to eliminate everything before and after the JSON contained in a specific part of a webpage so I can send that to a PHP script. I've tried a number of ways to get rid of the container content but all of them so far have failed, including one method that has worked in the exact same syntax for related purposes:

The characters that are between the two asterisks (**) at the beginning and end I need removed:

```
**var songs = [**{"timestamp":1555176393000,"title":"Enter Sandman","trackId":"ba_5cbb546d-5c1c-490e-9908-761b89dd5166","artist":"Metallica","artistId":"52_65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab","album":"Metallica","albumId":"d0_6e729716-c0eb-3f50-a740-96ac173be50d","npe_id":"3cc5fe24d0ffcbb9152d861f27ae801660"},{"timestamp":1555176702000,"title":"Start Me Up","trackId":"76_d0b86399-11e5-4d11-b4fe-ce4b3f9a4736","artist":"The Rolling Stones","artistId":"1b_b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f598","album":"Tattoo You","albumId":"d1_778b345b-e8a1-4054-b5ba-c611d3fda421","npe_id":"f0dc0ab12ef99a6e0087cad12886509b7b"},{"timestamp":1555176909000,"title":"Fame","trackId":"4e_cdef4b88-7314-431a-9cdd-d457296a65b7","artist":"David Bowie","artistId":"ab_5441c29d-3602-4898-b1a1-b77fa23b8e50","album":"Best of Bowie","albumId":"21_3709ee5a-d087-370f-afb4-f730092c7a94","npe_id":"2b8b3a170baa77125891d72a0474d3343a"},{"timestamp":1555177158000,"title":"Rocket","trackId":"34_aa5b9053-849e-4788-972f-7941303175b6","artist":"Def Leppard","artistId":"c1_7249b899-8db8-43e7-9e6e-22f1e736024e","album":"Hysteria","albumId":"06_de5cf055-d875-41f8-9261-89b11b7ff145","npe_id":"0d87b580f140a85feaebc7d77f75db2a3d"},{"timestamp":1555177826000,"title":"Mama, I'm Coming Home","trackId":"cb_e5b09171-9527-4d24-8ab6-1e922fdd66d3","artist":"Ozzy Osbourne","artistId":"4b_8aa5b65a-5b3c-4029-92bf-47a544356934","album":"No More Tears","albumId":"66_8f3d5a65-036c-3260-b9bb-36f1d0d80c11","npe_id":"6b766464fe945f275bf478192dcd33cfdc"},{"timestamp":1555178076000,"title":"Gold Dust Woman","trackId":"a4_ef8c1eca-f344-4bfb-82ea-763aa8aeaad9","artist":"Fleetwood Mac","artistId":"66_bd13909f-1c29-4c27-a874-d4aaf27c5b1a","album":"2010-01-08: The Rock Boat X, Lido Deck, Carnival Inspiration","albumId":"80_4f229af0-2afc-431d-87ff-f7f6af66268e","npe_id":"f6417d98fd1fefcca227d82a8ac9b84197"},{"timestamp":1555178363000,"title":"With or Without You","trackId":"79_6b9a509f-6907-4a6e-9345-2f12da09ba4b","artist":"U2","artistId":"26_a3cb23fc-acd3-4ce0-8f36-1e5aa6a18432","album":"The Joshua Tree","albumId":"0c_d287c703-5c25-3181-85d4-4d8c1a7d8ecd","npe_id":"23b19420196b28e2156ecda87c11b882e0"},{"timestamp":1555178654000,"title":"Who Are You","trackId":"7d_431b9746-c6ec-489d-9199-c83676171ae8","artist":"The Who","artistId":"22_f2fa2f0c-b6d7-4d09-be35-910c110bb342","album":"Who Are You","albumId":"40_b255da2c-6583-35f9-95e3-ef5f9c14e868","npe_id":"e01896f74f24968bb7727eaafbf6250b8f"},{"timestamp":1555179031000,"title":"Authority Song","trackId":"31_f5ff19f7-95f3-4a22-8996-3788c264e0b8","artist":"John Mellencamp","artistId":"4d_0aad6b52-fd93-4ea4-9c5d-1f66e1bc9f0a","album":"Words & Music: John Mellencamp's Greatest Hits","albumId":"9e_1240c510-7015-4484-baac-ce17f5277ea1","npe_id":"244785e3b1d75effb9fdecbb6df76b009f"},{"timestamp":1555179256000,"title":"Touch Me","trackId":"9d_1dd1f86c-2120-45f3-ac9f-3c87257fe414","artist":"The Doors","artistId":"13_9efff43b-3b29-4082-824e-bc82f646f93d","album":"The Soft Parade","albumId":"db_c29d7552-b5df-42b8-aae7-03d1e250cb3a","npe_id":"1b5d155eb2eeee6fc1fdb50a94b100669c"}]**; <ol class="songs tracks"></ol>**
```

Here is the shell script which produces the above at present:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory >/var/tmp/wklh$1.a.txt
pta=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.a.txt | grep songs > /var/tmp/wklh$1.b.txt`
ptb=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.b.txt | sed -n -e '/var songs = /,/; <span title/ p' > /var/tmp/wklh$1.c.txt`
ptc=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.c.txt | grep songs > /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
#ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/var songs = [//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
#ptd=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt | sed -i 's/}]; <ol class="songs tracks"></ol>//g' /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`

json=`cat /var/tmp/wklh$1.d.txt`
echo $json

metadata=`php /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php $json`
echo $metadata
```

The commented out lines are what I was trying to use to remove the extraneous content, since it is predictable every time. However, when uncommented, I get the following errors:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
```

I've examined my sed statement, but I can't find any discrepancies between how I use it here and in other working shell scripts.

Is there actually a syntax error here (or unallowed characters)? Or is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: If you use `/` as the delimiter of the `s` command, you need to escape any `/` in the pattern or replacement parts.

Comment: BTW, this question could be a lot more succinct if you made a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are special to sed. Simply escape them.

```
s/var songs = \[//g
```

If you use slash `/` as the regex delimiter, it  becomes special. Either escape it or use a different delimiter.

```
s/}]; <ol class="songs tracks"><\/ol>//g
s|}]; <ol class="songs tracks"></ol>||g
```

Comment: Thank you! The stuff at the beginning is gone but not the stuff at the end. Does the ] at the end also need to be escaped? (I tried it both ways)

Comment: OK, splitting it up into 3 separate sed statements worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Your shell script has serious issues.

The syntax

```
variable=`commands`
```

takes the output of `commands` and assigns it to `variable`. But in every case, you are redirecting all output to a file; so the variable will always be empty.

Unless you need the temporary files for reasons which are not revealed in your question (such as maybe being able to check how many bytes of output you got in each temporary file for a monitoring report, or something like that), a pipeline would be much superior.

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -v --silent http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory |
grep songs |
sed -n -e '/var songs = /,/; <span title/ p' |
grep songs |
php /etc/asterisk/scripts/music/wklh.php
```

This also does away with the [useless uses of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and the [useless uses of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and so also coincidentally removes the [quoting errors](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642). The `grep x | sed -n 's/y/z/p'` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which can easily be refactored to `sed -n '/x/s/y/z/p'`

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed,

```
sed -Ez 's/^\*\*[^\*]+\*\*(.+)]\*\*[^\*]+\*\*\s*$/\1/' d
```

remove last `]` too, to correctly balance the Json